# registering a service worker in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, graphql, service-worker

Our server is setup as follows, using react, graphql, mongo and express:

```
public  
  index.html  
  service.js  
src  
  assets  
  client (has 2 client side js files)  
  components (for react)  
    game.jsx  
  server (graphql server)  
    server.js
```

I need to register a service worker so that I can send push notification to players; the call is from game.jsx (the one that gets loaded when I want the serviceWorker to be registered):

```
const swreg = await navigator.serviceworker.register('service.js');
```

This causes a get request to ourURL.com/service.js (hence why I have service.js under public, as that's where it's served)

This is fine and dandy, but then I keep getting import errors in service.js:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

this is the offending code in service.js:

```
import { saveSubscription } from "src/queries/queries";
```

Where saveSubscription is a graphql mutation call, and is defined in src/queries/queries.js.

I have tried other forms of importing, but they give me a syntax error of somekind. Googling told me that I need a type="module" tag, which obviously does not apply to this case.
How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it... sort of.

I removed the import line, and instead used a fetch within the function.

```
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST", // get can't have body
  'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
  body: JSON.stringify({graphQLQuery})
});
```